# Slow performance in populating DataGridView with large amount of data VB.NET <- SQL

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a problem with populating a data grid in my WPF VB.NET project.
This is my code for calling a stored procedure in my local SQL Server database:

```vb
Public Class SQL
    Private Const ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\TestVFE;Initial Catalog=testVFE;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

    Private Shared Connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    Public Shared Sub OpenConnection()
        If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Connection.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub CloseConnection()
        If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Connection.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetLast1000Rows() As DataTable
        OpenConnection()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("GetLast1000Rows", Connection)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim results As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(results)
        CloseConnection()
        Return results
    End Function
```

This is the main window:

```vb
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub ResultsGrid_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ResultsGrid.Loaded
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = SQL.GetLast1000Rows
        ResultsGrid.RowHeaderStyle = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing
        ResultsGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView
    End Sub

End Class
```

In debug mode, to fetch data from SQL Server, it takes like 500-800ms, but when the entire code is executed, it needs to wait for example some times for around 2 minutes to populate 2000 rows with 123 columns (biggest data is 4 column nvarchar 40 in table, rest of them are much smaller).

Can someone help me improve this?

Comment: Why are you using `DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode` in a WPF app when it is specific to the WinForms `DataGridView`? You must have `Option Strict Off` for that to even compile, so you should start by fixing that.

Comment: I just noticed that you also refer to `DataGridView` in the title too. `DataGridView` is specific to WinForns and doesn't have an `ItemsSource` property, so clearly you're not using one. It is presumably a WPF `DataGrid`.

Comment: Do you really need all the 2000 rows with 123 columns?

Comment: DefaultView is a DataView which implements IBindingListView which causes measurable delays due to the many eventhandlers being created and bound. Maybe a simple List<T> would be a better ItemsSource. And btw, WPF DataGrid has RowVirtualization capabilities.

Comment: `ResultsGrid.RowHeaderStyle = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing` makes no sense and should also not compile

Comment: Is your DataGrid Autogenerating Columns? This could also be a source of delay.